# Use global variables in a class

Tags: php, sql, class, oop

I'm trying to create a pagination class and use a variable from outside the class.

But it's giving me the fatal error "Call to a member function query() on a non-object".

This is the index file:

```
$db = new DB_MySQL("localhost", "root", "", "test"); // connect to the database
include_once("pagi.php");

$pagination = new pagi();
$records = $pagination->get_records("SELECT * FROM `table`");
```

And this is the pagi.php file:

```
class pagi {

    public function get_records($q) {
        $x = $db->query($q);
        return $db->fetch($x);
    }

}
```

Is it possible to use this variable from out side of the class inside the class, without creating a new one inside the class?

Comment: You can do `global $db;` inside the method, but a better approach is to use a singleton, dependency injection, or DB factory pattern to obviate the need for a global variable.

Comment: Most notably `new pagi($db);` might be advisable. Copy it from your constructor into an object property for later use. Albeit I personally don't frown on a single global resource. (You just need to be sure your app never outgrows a single database, that is.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish
Thank you that works well :)

but can you please provide any references to all what you just said :D
because i actually know nothing about any of them ^_^

Comment: @mario thank you for the advice.. I'll take that in consideration :)

Comment: What @mario is demonstrating is [dependency injection](http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html).

Comment: Singletons give you a way to define and obtain only one instance, even with multiple requests (think `DB::getInstance('mydb')`). Some consider singletons to be a bad practice, but I feel a lot of it comes down to orthodoxy and coding practices used in a project. For instance, there is a vocal group of critics who despise dependency injection. Six and one-half-dozen. Use what's appropriate for your project.

Comment: Of course, there's a *really really loud* crew of folk who think globals are eViL, vile things (or just [bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)). As @mario notes, with due care, they're not necessarily a problem, especially if you are the only developer of the codebase. In reality, they're just a tool, but as you progress as a developer, you'll learn to avoid them in most cases.

Comment: well thank you so much @JaredFarrish i actually learned a lot today and i think I'll use dependency injection.. as it's kind of easy to understand :D

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The correct way to solve this would be to inject the database object into the other class ([dependency injection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)):

```
$db = new DB_MySQL("localhost", "root", "", "test"); // connect to the database
include_once("pagi.php");

$pagination = new Paginator($db);
$records = $pagination->get_records("SELECT the, fields, you, want, to retrieve FROM `table`");

class Paginator
{    
    protected $db;

    // Might be better to use some generic db interface as typehint when available
    public function __construct(DB_MySQL $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function get_records($q) {
        $x = $this->db->query($q);
        return $this->db->fetch($x);
    }

}
```

Another way you could solve it is by injecting the instance of the database class into the method that uses it:

```
$db = new DB_MySQL("localhost", "root", "", "test"); // connect to the database
include_once("pagi.php");

$pagination = new Paginator();
$records = $pagination->get_records("SELECT the, fields, you, want, to retrieve FROM `table`", $db);

class Paginator
{
    public function get_records($q, DB_MySQL $db) {
        $x = $db->query($q);
        return $db->fetch($x);
    }

}
```

Whichever method you choose depends on the situation. If only one method needs an instance of the database you can just inject it into the method, otherwise I would inject it into the constructor of the class.

Also note that I have renamed your class from `pagi` to `Paginator`. Paginator is a better name IMHO for the class because it is clear for other people (re)viewing your code. Also note that I have made the first letter uppercase.

Another thing I have done is changed the query to select the fields you are using instead of using the "wildcard" `*`. This is for the same reason I have changed the classname: People (re)viewing your code will know exactly what fields will be retrieved without checking the database and/or the result.

**Update**

Because answer gave rise to a discussion regarding why I would go the dependency injection route instead of declaring the object `global`, I would like to clarify why I would use dependency injection over the `global` keyword: When you have a method like:

```
function get_records($q) {
    global $db;

    $x = $db->query($q);
    return $db->fetch($x);
}
```

When you are using the above method somewhere it isn't clear that the class or method uses depends on `$db`. Hence it is a hidden dependency. Another reason why the above is bad is because you have tightly coupled the `$db` instance (thus the `DB_MySQL`) class to that method / class. What if you need to use 2 databases at some point. Now you would have to go through all code to change `global $db` to `global $db2`. You should never need to change your code just to switch to another database. For this reason, you should not do:

```
function get_records($q) {
    $db = new DB_MySQL("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    $x = $db->query($q);
    return $db->fetch($x);
}
```

Again, this is a hidden dependency, and tightly couples the `DB_MySQL` class to the method / class. Because of this it is also impossible to properly unit test the `Paginator` class. Instead of testing only the unit (the `Paginator` class) you are also testing the `DB_MySQL` class at the same time. And what if you have multiple tightly coupled dependencies? Now you are suddenly testing several classes with your so called unit tests. So when using dependency injection you can easily switch to another database class, or even a mocked one for testing purposes. Besides the benefit of testing only one unit (you don't have to worry about getting wrong results because of dependencies) it will also make sure your tests will finish fast.

Some people may think the Singleton pattern is the correct way to get access to a database object, but it should be clear, having read all of the above, a singleton is basically just another way of making things `global`. It might look different, but it has the exact same characteristics and hence the same problems as `global`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, thought it might be a different language. `Paginate` might be a better class name, although I wonder as well if this is an appropriate use of a class construct.

Comment: @PeeHaa, can you explain why this is the _correct_ way? I've solved this exact solution with a factory class, which stores an instance of the `DB` class. The database is then queried like this: `AppName::Database()->query()`. Can you indicate what the upsides of your approach are, especially compared to the (static) Factory pattern?

Comment: @creativedutchmen Where are you going to call that method from? From inside another class? If your answer is going to be "yes" I'm really wondering how you are going to test that class. You cannot mock out the database class anymore because you have tightly coupled the database class to the paginator class and it's hard to tell you are using the database class (hidden dependencies). Also note that you have basically created another `global` method right now.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Aha! So the main difference is in the _hidden_ nature of the dependency? I disagree with you that the database class is tightly coupled at this stage: I would even say it looser than your approach. For example, if you want to change DB later on (to postgre, for example), you will have to change all your code from `$db = new DB_MySQL()` to `$db = new DB_PostgreSQL()`;. I just have to let the `Database` function return an instance of the `DB_PostgreSQL` class instead. Sure, there is a very tight dependency on the `App` class, but I don't really see this a bad thing.

Comment: @PeeHaa What should I do if I want to do a query into a static method?

Comment: @creativedutchmen: Better get the goods of both worlds. Have a central place where you configure which database class to use for *your* application but make your code work with any kind of database class. That would allow you not only to not change the code when the configuration changes but also to not change the whole code when only part of the code changes (e.g. one part is using database 1, another database 2). You do not need to put both against each other but should think about how to bring both together. A global path is often *easy* first but you should know about the price.

Comment: Thanks guys for clearing this up. I guess the main reason I never really felt the downside of my approach is because I am not a big fan of unit testing. I have done it for a while, but it always gave me a fake sense of bug-free-ness. Even though I had tested everything, bugs would still pop up. Maybe I am just doing it wrong, though:)

Comment: @PeeHaa static methods exists. They are not technically deprecated. So if I need a static method, I can write it. So my question: according to your answer, what is the best way to do it? (it's just a question for complete the answer) :)

Comment: My point is that you just don't need a `static` method. Unless you can provide me with a use case where a `static` cannot be replaced with dependency injection.

Answer (score 6):

Although I do agree that the dependency model is nice, for the database, I personally use a static connection that is available to all instances of the database class and the create instances to query whenever I need one. Here is an example:

```
<?php
//define a database class
class DB {
    //the static connection.
    //This is available to all instances of the class as the same connection.
    private static $_conn;

    //store the result available to all methods
    private $result;
    //store the last query available to all methods
    private $lastQuery;

    //static connection function. connects to the database and stores that connection statically.       
    public static function connect($host, $user, $pass, $db){
        self::$_conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    }

    //standard function for doing queries. uses the static connnection property.
    public function query($query){
        $this->lastQuery = $query;
        $this->result = mysqli_query(self::$_conn, $query);
        //process result, return expected output.
    }
}

//create connection to the database, this connection will be used in all instances of DB class
DB::connect('local', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS');

//create instance to query
$test = new DB;
//do query
$test->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE");

//test function
function foo(){
    //create instance to use in this function
    $bar = new DB;
    //do query
    $bar->query("SELECT * FROM OTHER_TABLE");
    //return results
    return $bar->fetchArray();
}
```

That way I can create all the instances I want of DB within any function, method...etc and use that local instance of the class to do all my queries. All instances use the same connection.

One thing to note though is that this only allows for one connection to the database per defined class but I only use one so this isn't an issue for me.

Comment: This is basically a slightly unusual variant of the Singleton pattern: all your DB "objects" exist only to wrap static methods, so you could equally write `DB::query("SELECT * FROM OTHER_TABLE");` or have a method `DB::singleton();` that returned the ready-connected object. It doesn't solve the issue of coupling, because you still have a "global" variable (DB::$_conn) which cannot be switched out for testing or future expansion.

Answer (score 3):

you could add the db-connection (`$db`) to the call of the `get_records` method:

Here are only the relevant lines of code:

First file:

```
$records = $pagination->get_records("SELECT * FROM `table`", $db);
```

Second file:

```
public function get_records($q, $db) {
```

Comment: While not an ideal solution, this is better than a static or global variable, as you are effectively performing Dependency Injection every time you call the method. The advantage of passing it in the constructor is that you only have to do it once, rather than on every method.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers thus far are definitely preferable to using a global since that will ruin your encapsulation (eg you'd need to have that object defined prior to calling that method).

It's much better to enforce that in the method signature or not use a class.