# How can i return more than 1 values from a foreach loop using PHP

Tags: php, function

Here's my function

```
function GetUser($id)
{
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT lname,fname,mi FROM user WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    foreach($stmt as $name){
        $lname = $name['lname'];
        $lname = $name['fname'];
        $mi = $name['mi'];
    }

    return //what to put here?
}
```

Here's my code to use the function

```
include 'function.php';
$names = GetUser($_SESSION['id']);
//what's next?
```

How can i retrieve the $lname,$fname and $mi from the function? Need any help and suggestions. Thank you :)

Comment: What's wrong with using a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: I recommend taking an object-oriented approach and creating a User object which wraps the user values.  Alternatively, you can just return the three values in an array.

Comment: you can use std class as well for this purpose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters don't use the [`global` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923272/use-global-variables-in-a-class/11923384#11923384), but inject the variable you need. Second why don't you return an array?:

```
function getUser($pdo, $id)
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT lname,fname,mi FROM user WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));

    $result = array();
    foreach($stmt as $name){
        $result['lname'] = $name['lname'];
        $result['fname'] = $name['fname'];
        $result['mi']  = $name['mi'];
    }

    return $result;
}

$result = getUser($pdo, 1);
var_dump($result);
```

Note that this will only return the **last** result. If you want it all:

```
function getUser($pdo, $id)
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT lname,fname,mi FROM user WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

$result = getUser($pdo, 1);
var_dump($result);
```

Also note that I have made your function name starting with a normal letter instead of a capital. The "normal" naming convention is that classes start with a capital, but function / methods with a normal one.

If you want to retrieve the information based on the first solution you would do:

```
echo $result['lname'];
```

If you want to retrieve the information based on the second solution you would do:

```
echo $result[0]['lname'];
```

Comment: yes i am a starter. why should I not use global? i have many functions that's why I use global so that i will not use that same line of code over and over again? hehe :) thanks

Comment: No worries. Everybody has to start somewhere. :-) See the linked post at the top of my answer and also see the comments/discussion underneath that answer.

Comment: thanks sir! but how can i retrieve every each of the values like i want to echo the names: echo $lname.', '.$fname.' '.$mi.'.'?

Answer (score 3):

```
function GetUser($id)
{
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT lname,fname,mi FROM user WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    foreach($stmt as $name){
        $lname = $name['lname'];
        $lname = $name['fname'];
        $mi = $name['mi'];
    }

    return array(
        "$lname" => $lname,
        "$fname" => $fname,
        "$mi" => $mi
     );
}
```

This is what's next part:

```
include 'function.php';
$myArray = GetUser($_SESSION['id']);
$fname = $myArray["$fname"];
$lname = $myArray["$lname"];
$mi = $myArray["$mi"];
```

Or:

```
include 'function.php';
$myArray = GetUser($_SESSION['id']);
$fname = $myArray[0];
$lname = $myArray[1];
$mi = $myArray[2];
```

Comment: see the revised version above. @SuiGo

Comment: choose this one as answer if it helped you @SuiGo :)

Comment: @DerikNelson You are running your `return array() { }` as a function which it isn't

Answer (score 1):

```
return array(
    "lname" => $lname,
    "fname" => $fname,
    "mi" => $mi
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetUser($id) {
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT lname,fname,mi FROM user WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    return $stmt;
}


include 'function.php';
$names = GetUser($_SESSION['id']);
foreach($names as $name){
    $lname = $name['lname'];
    $lname = $name['fname'];
    $mi = $name['mi'];
}
```

Not tested, but I think it should work

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetUser($id)
{
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT lname,fname,mi FROM user WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
   return count($stmt)==1?$stmt[0]:null; //you may have nothing returned from the database so return null
}
```

Then:

```
include 'function.php';
$names = GetUser($_SESSION['id']);
if ($names){   //if this is not null then get the properties
echo $names['fname'];
echo $names['lname'];
echo $names['mi'];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but which is better using this type of approach or the array ? :)