# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-objec on php class and function

Tags: php, pdo

```
<?php
    try{
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_SERVER;dbname=$DB_NAME",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
    }

class SessionManager {

        var $life_time;
        function SessionManager() {
            global $conn;
            $this->life_time = get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime");

            // Register this object as the session handler
            session_set_save_handler( 
                array( &$this, "open" ), 
                array( &$this, "close" ),
                array( &$this, "read" ),
                array( &$this, "write" ),
                array( &$this, "destroy"),
                array( &$this, "gc" )
            );
        }



        function read( $id ) {
            global $conn;
            $data = "";
            $time = time();
            $newid = $id;       
            $sql = "SELECT session_data FROM session_tmp WHERE session_id=? AND expired_date > ?";
            $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $result = $q->execute(array($newid, $time));
            while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $data = $row['session_data'];
            }
            return $data;
        }


        function write( $id, $data ) {            
            $time = time() + $this->life_time;
            global $conn;
            $newid = $id;
            $newdata = $data;
            $sql = "SELECT session_id FROM session_tmp WHERE session_id = ?"; // error happen here!!!!
            $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $result = $q->execute(array($newid));
            return TRUE;
        }
}
```

I add `global $conn;` onto `function read()` and it fix the error. I don't know why `global $conn;` cannot fix the error on `function write()`. How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, a variable like `$conn` is available in a function **if and only if it was defined inside the function**. The word 'defined inside of' means 'assigned inside of'.

In your case, `$conn` is not defined in the `write()` function, but **outside of all functions**. Therefore, you need to tell `write()` that it should refer to the global variable $conn. This is done using

```
   global $conn;
```

Note, that use of `global` is **strongly bad code style**! You should never need to use `global`.

Instead of global, you might do something like this:

```
// This class should actually be a singleton class
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
//
class CDBSession {

  protected 
    $conn;

  public function __construct( $DB_SERVER, $DB_NAME, $DB_USER,$DB_PASS ) {

      $this->conn 
         = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_SERVER;dbname=$DB_NAME",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);

  } // __construct

  public function getPDO() {

      return $this->conn;

  }      

}

class SessionManager {

  protected 
    $_PDOSession;

  public function __construct( CDBSession $theDBSession ) {

      $this->_PDOSession = $theDBSession;

  } // __construct


  ... other methods need to access $this->_PDOSession->getPDO() too ...

} // class SessionManager
```

Finally, you have to use SessionManager like this:

```
$mySessionManager 
  = new SessionManager(new CDBSession($DB_SERVER, $DB_NAME, $DB_USER,$DB_PASS));
```

Comment: I tested ur code, it show error message : Parse error: parse error, expecting T_CATCH on the line of close tag '} // _construct'

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry, just copied your incomplete try{} construct ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't that mean you are going to end up with a lot of database instances throughout your application?

Comment: In case you create one Sessionmanager and move it around in your application, not. Yes, one would better create a single instance version of SessionManager. I just wanted to point out how to work without global.

Comment: IMHO It would be better to [inject the database class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923272/use-global-variables-in-a-class/11923384#11923384) into the `SessionManager` class.

Comment: Still have error ... **Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to SessionManager::__construct() must be an instance of CSBSession, none given**