# PHP PDO simple insert or update function

Tags: php, pdo, insert-update

In trying to create a simple PHP PDO update function that if the field is not found would insert it, I created this little snippet.

```
function updateorcreate($table,$name,$value){
    global $sodb;
    $pro = $sodb->prepare("UPDATE `$table` SET value = :value WHERE field = :name");
    if(!$pro){
        $pro = $sodb->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` (field,value) VALUES (:name,:value)");
    }
    $pro->execute(array(':name'=>$name,':value'=>$value));
}
```

It does not detect though if the update function is going to work with `if(!$pro);` How would we make this one work.

Comment: I;m still getting used to it but am not going back to mySQL

Comment: -1 [for using `global`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11923384/508666)

Comment: You first need to `execute()` it before you can tell whether the update caused rows to get updated using `numRows()`, but if the field already exists with the same value you might get unintended results as well.

Comment: The update query doesn't give an error, it's a valid query that doesn't update any records.

Comment: @Lex but he only executes his first query at the bottom, so the if-condition is useless.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are assigning `$pro` to the prepare, not the execute statement.

Having said that, if you are using mysql you can use the `insert... on duplicate key update` syntax.

```
insert into $table (field, value) values (:name, :value) on duplicate key update value=:value2
```

You can't use the same bound param twice, but you can set two bound params to the same value.

Edit: This mysql syntax will *only* work where a key (primary or another unique) is present and would cause an insert to fail.

Comment: This is what I tried:                                                         function updateorcreate($table,$name,$value){
 global $sodb;
 $pro = $sodb->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (field, value) values (:name, :value) ON DUPLICATE KEY update value = :value2");
 $pro->execute(array(':name'=>$name,':value'=>$value,':value2'=>$value));
}

Comment: @RobinKnight Sorry, I should have mentioned it right off the bat, you do have a unique constraint set on the table for the column `field` yes?

Comment: No perhaps I ought to as there should be no reason they would ever repeat

Comment: @RobinKnight Sorry about that mate, yes, the syntax will only work if the column is constrained. Apologies, should have mentioned that right from the start :(

Comment: PDO really needs to allow you to use the same parameter twice.

Answer (score 2):

If it's mysql-only you could try INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to execute it.

Apart from that, this is a dodgy way of doing this. It would be better to start a transaction, do a SELECT and then determine what to do (INSERT or UPDATE). Just checking whether the UPDATE query succeeded doesn't suffice, it succeeds when no row is found too.

Comment: OK, I was trying to see if we could bypass that step but if its not safe then I won't

Comment: `SELECT` is a rather dodgy way of doing it too.  Better would be to have a unique key on the field, and then use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.

Comment: I never read he wants to avoid duplication altogether. He just doesn't want it in this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
    PDO::exec()
```

returns 1 if inserted. 
2 if the row has been updated.

for prepared statements,

```
    PDOStatement::execute()
```

You can try,

```
    PDOStement::rowCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are PHP `PDO` helper functions for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`

`INSERT` function:

```
function basicInsertQuery($tableName,$values = array()){

/*
//
USAGE INSERT FUNCTİON
    $values = [
        "column" => $value,               
    ];
    $result =  basicInsertQuery("bulk_operations",$values);
*/

try {
    global $pdo;

    foreach ($values as $field => $v)
        $vals[] = ':' . $field;

    $ins = implode(',', $vals);
    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($values));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($fields) VALUES ($vals)";

    $rows = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($values as $k => $vl)
    {
        $rows->bindValue(':' . $k, $l);
    }
    $result = $rows->execute();
    return $result;
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
   return $th;
}    
}
```

`UPDATE` function:

```
function basicUpdateQuery($tableName,  $values = array(), $where = array()) {

/*
*USAGE UPDATE FUNCTİON

    $valueArr = [ column => "value",  ];
    $whereArr = [ column => "value",  ];
    $result = basicUpdateQuery("bulk_operations",$valueArr, $whereArr);
*/
try {        
    global $pdo;

    //set value
    foreach ($values as $field => $v)
        $ins[] = $field. '= :' . $field;
    $ins = implode(',', $ins);

    //where value
    foreach ($where as $fieldw => $vw)
        $inswhere[] = $fieldw. '= :' . $fieldw;
    $inswhere = implode(' && ', $inswhere);


    $sql = "UPDATE  $tableName SET $ins WHERE $inswhere";    
    $rows = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($values as $f => $v){
        $rows->bindValue(':' . $f, $v);
    }
    foreach ($where as $k => $l){
        $rows->bindValue(':' . $k, $l);
    }
    $result = $rows->execute();

    return $result;
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    return $th;
}

}
```