# Public variable use in all functions using PHP class

Tags: php

Suppose that I have the PHP code as below:

```
class modual {
  public $glo;

  static public function SaveData($RDesTechni = 1,$RCapacity = 2){
    try{
      $sql = "INSERT INTO tblworkfaire VALUES('',$RDesTechni,$RCapacity)";
      $qry=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
      $id = mysql_insert_id();
      $glo = $id;
    }
    catch(exception $e){
      echo $e;
    }
  }

  static public function ListData(){
    try {
      include("connectdb.php");

      $query = "SELECT * FROM tblworkfaire where id=".$glo;

      return $query;
    }
    catch(exception $e){
      echo $e;
    }
  }
}
```

**What I need:**

I want to get the `$id` to use in the function `static public function ListData()` but it does not work.

**Problems:**

It does not work it shows me the error `undefined $glo` How I fix this? Anyone help me please. Thanks.

Comment: [Related read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923272/use-global-variables-in-a-class/11923384#11923384)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public static` instead of `static public`?

Comment: @bfavaretto: order of the keywords don't matter actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use *self* to access the variable, and it also needs to be *public static*.

```
class modual {
  public static $glo;

  static public function SaveData($RDesTechni = 1,$RCapacity = 2){
    try{
      self::$glo = 5;
    }
    catch(exception $e){
      echo $e;
    }
  }

  static public function ListData(){
    echo self::$glo;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into passing the parameter you need to the function?

```
static public function ListData( $glo ){
```

When you call the method, you include the value for the id:

```
$myModual->ListData($id);
```

In general, it's better design to pass variables to functions rather than use global variables.

You could also make a constructor for the class so that you store a value for $glo when an object of the class is initialized.