# should you use global classes in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a project and here's what my coding practice looks like.

- I load all the class files in config
- I create an instance of the VITAL classes in the configuration (ie. `$database = new Database()`). The non-vital classes get created within the pages.
- Inside the pages I just use `$database->query` to fetch data.
- Inside functions I call `global $database` and take it from there.

Is this practice normal? Discouraged? Encouraged? Which method of code structure do you implement when you work on a large project?

Comment: I would recommend something like singletons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP global in functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5166087/1409082) and [Use global variables in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11923272/1409082).

Comment: sorry for asking a question, i guess everyone on here is above me

Comment: I don't get why this question got down-voted so heavily. I am sure that many php programmers encounter this question at some point. To answer the question in a more detailed manner: You could use a [static class][1] or a [singleton][2] to avoid juggling with globals.

  [1]: http://de1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php
  [2]: http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.patterns.php

Answer (score 1):

Do not initiate classes you may not use, only these you will use for sure. For other use [autoloading](http://php.net/autoload) feature.

Comment: wow, wish i knew about autoload before.

Answer (score -2):

If you make your methods static, you don't need to pass a reference around.

```
class Database {
    static function query($...) {...}
    ...
}
```

You probably still want the constructor to initiate the connection, but once that's done you can simply call `Database::query(...)`.

Comment: Apparently this is called a Singleton class. I did not know that until I read Adam's comment on the question XD

Comment: the database class creates a new MySQLi object.. i don't want to create the object and connect that each time i want to execute a query. which is why i create it once, and then reuse it throughout the entire execution without actually passing the object by reference

Comment: That's what I tried to explain. Keep your constructor and call `new Database()` once at the start of your code, then use `Database::query()`.