# Bring a global into a class

Tags: php, class

If I have a config file with `$var = array('1', '2', '3');` How do I access it in a class without defining it as a constant? `var $class_var = $var` doesn't work. Previously, in procedural it was a matter of `function this { global $var; echo $var; }`.

Comment: You really don't want to use the `global` keyword http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923272/use-global-variables-in-a-class/11923384#11923384

Comment: `global` is a sign of doing it wrong, regardless of what 'it' is.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways.  You can pull it into your construct as a global:

```
class myclass{
    var $var;

    function __construct() {
        global $var;
        $this->var = $var;
    }
}
```

You can pass it as a variable when you instantiate the class:

```
class myclass{
    var $var;

    function __construct( $var ) {
        $this->var = $var;
    }
}

$class = new myclass( $var );
```

Not using globals if at all possible is generally preferred.