# is my cfg.php connection right?

Tags: php, database, oop

I have a quick question to you guys, i have created the CFG file which stores my database connection detail in two dimensional array. I then connect it to my PHP class file and make it launch the arrays stated in CFG file. As you can see below in my code:

cfg.php

```
 <?php
   $cfg['db']['host'] = 'localhost';
   $cfg['db']['user'] = 'root'; //your user name
   $cfg['db']['pass'] = ''; //your password 
   $cfg['db']['db'] = 'db3'; //your database
 ?>
```

and my class file :

```
 <?php

     require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . 'cfg.php');

class Database {

    private $dbConn; //stores the database connection

   public function __construct($dbConn)
     {
    global $cfg;
    mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die('Could not connect to MySQL server.');
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE)or die('Unable to select database: ');
    }



}
```

What i want to ask you is: is this right way of doing this? also what do I need to add in my index to see that it is connected. and the output of the database content. Thank you in advance for taking time and reading my problem. Cheerio.

Edit :

```
      <?php

        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . 'cfg.php');

  class Database {

     private $dbConn; //stores the database connection

public function __construct($dbConn)
{
    global $cfg;
    mysqli_connect($cfg['db']['host'], $cfg['db']['user'], $cfg['db']['pass'])
    or die('Could not connect to MySQL server.');
    mysqli_select_db($dbConn, $cfg['db']['db'])
    or die('Unable to select database: ');
}


}
```

Does this looks better now? If yes. How do i connect it with the index.php file where my forms will be stored. say to output the message of (connected to database). Thank you.

EDIT: changed to mysqli and now when selecting the database it states that i am missing the database name. Not sure where to put that and how to alter it. Thank you.

EDIT: I am on my way to create functions for 'Select' 'Insert' and 'Delete' . If any of you can point me do a great source of information which will help me in my research it will be most appreciated.

Comment: You are not using the array, but some constants? However, this is not the right way, even you would be using the array. Starting from using mysql_* and global variables is bad. On the other hand read about Dependency injection

Comment: [Please, stop using mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1238019) in new code, they are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Instead of, have a look on [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), and use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @zessx I have changed that, throws me an error (edited the main article) not sure of what to add. If you could throw some more advice. Thank you.

Comment: @user2919681 You now need to keep a trace of your connexion : `$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass); mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname);`

Comment: @user2919681 Ya, I wrote a simplified version.

Comment: @zessex Is this what you mean? 
       `global $cfg;
         mysqli_connect($cfg['db']['host'], $cfg['db']['user'], $cfg['db']['pass'])
         or die('Could not connect to MySQL server.');
          mysqli_select_db($dbConn, $cfg['db']['db'])
          or die('Unable to select database: ');`

Comment: @zessex I will also have to add the `Select` `Delete` and `Insert` functions. Any advice where to look for clues or more information, as you can tell i am not that bright in all of the PHP class communications and still will somehow have to out put this function in to the form version where user can use that. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using constants instead of the actual values from your config in your `mysql_connect()` function, so that wouldn't work. You would need to do it this way:

`mysql_connect($cfg['db']['host'], $cfg['db']['user'], $cfg['db']['pass'])`

Aside from that and OO paradigms, it would probably be better if you used PHP's mysqli ([as stated here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), as PHP's `mysql_` is pretty outdated.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the advice although this were the tasks which i am doing (some self studies) not done any PHP before. Will read your links, but using this way i showed how can i check that the connection is there and the DB content can be shown?

Comment: When the connection fails the `mysql_connect()` function will return "FALSE", you can check it this way (analog to the example from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)): ```$link = mysql_connect($cfg['db']['host'], $cfg['db']['user'], $cfg['db']['pass']); if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }``` -- The `die()` function here will end the script in case of failure, there are better ways to [solve this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) when working with objects, you should try that later on.

Answer (score 0):

No you are not doing it correctly. By using this line

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . 'cfg.php');
```

in your class file you have introduced a somewhat tight coupling to the config file and you have made it hard to swap it out for other credentials. I.e. you will have to change the file with the Database class in it to change the credentials. So start by dropping that include there.

Another thing you do is using the [`global` keyword which is as far from OOP as you could possibly get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923272/use-global-variables-in-a-class/11923384#11923384). Inject the information the class needs instead.

Also you are using the ancient, deprecated and soon to be removed `mysql_*` API. You are also calling the execution of your script of something fails (`or die()`) which makes it impossible to integrate your code in a project and also makes it impossible to correctly handle errors (i.e. custom error page).

When upgrading to a better database API (e.g. PDO) you even don't have the need anymore to use a database class at all.

The above would simply look something like the following:

*bootstrap.php*

```
try {
    $dbConnection = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

    $dbConnection->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    // nicely handle error here
}
```

Alternatively you could implement [lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/508666) for the database connection depending on your requirements.
As you can see now there is no need for an external config file (you can just change the credentials here in the bootstrap file) and there is no need for a database class.

Comment: Unfortunately I have received strict task to use exactly that type of connection to cfg file which contains two dimensional array.

Comment: Well the requirements (in this specific case) doesn't make much sense. You can include the config file in the bootstrap file if that makes you happy.