# Object lookup in PHP without using Singleton

Tags: php, oop

In PHP, we can easy to reference an object in `any classes` using singleton, e.g.

```
$obj = SingletonClass::getInstance();
```

If I am not using singleton, are there any alternative?

Comment: I cannot make sense of the question.

Comment: Store it in a variable? What are you asking here?

Comment: He's asking if it's possible to check if there's already an instance of an object **without** using the `singleton pattern` - i guess

Comment: go through every single entry in the `$GLOBALS` and evaluate whether its an `INSTANCEOF ClassName` ?!

Comment: It would be interesting to know WHY you don't / can't use singleton ?

Comment: @KhorneHoly: How did you reach that conclusion? The sample code does not *check* anything, it *does* something.

Comment: @Jon Bad wording from me, should've been `if it's possible to GET an instance of an object if it exists, else create one, without singleton`.. like, use singleton without singleton

Comment: @KhorneHoly use a factory to produce instances, said factory then can internally store it and reuse. Like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208

Answer (score 0):

> If I am not using a Singleton, are there any alternatives?

Yes, this thing is called *Dependency Injection* and it has been discussed million times before.
Basically that means, you instantiate a class, and then pass its instance around another classes that require it. For example:

```
$pdo = new PDO(....);

$userGateway = new UserGateway($pdo);
$imageGateway = new ImageGateway($pdo);
```

As you can see, the same instance is shared across those classes.

Answer (score -1):

I will recommend singleton, but you can try something like that:

```
$GLOBAL = null;
```

And every time you would like to initate it:

```
if ($GLOBAL != null()) {
    $GLOBAL = new YourObject();
}
```

Comment: i wouldn't override the `$GLOBAL` variable...

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 That's not a `$GLOBAL`, but `$GLOBALS`

Answer (score -2):

Simply instantiate your object in the global scope. An example follows below:

```
#file1.php
require_once('file2.php');
$instance = new ClassName();

#file2.php
function do_something()
{
    global $instance;
    #do stuff with with
}
```

Comment: wow just wow. `Global`s are never a solution. Especially not when the question is tagged OOP

Comment: @PeeHaa if you read his question, you'd realise he was searching for a way to use a single object instance, without making the class a `Singleton`. Globals are the cleanest way to do that, so long as the developer stays aware of what he's declared. So you know, the question is tagged `OOP` because he's interested in `Classes` and `Objects`.

Comment: http://triggerplug.com/2013/11/30/hahaha-no-meme-of-the-day/. On a more serious note: [Use global variables in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11923384/508666)